# How change text view on a given day in Android Studio?

Tags: android, textview

I want to create an event such that on a given day that I select a new message will appear. For example: on January 1st, I might want it to say "Hello" and then on January 5th the text changes to "Hey" or some other sort of message that I decide beforehand that will appear on a day I pick. Any ideas on how to do this or where I could look to set me in the right direction?

Comment: Um...check the date and then display a message?

Comment: There should be 365 cases and one extra in case of leap year. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I made this in Eclipse. Same thing will work in Android. Instead of System.out.println(); you do textView.setText();

```
public class CheckDay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE)); //prints 4
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); //6 (weeks start on sunday)
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)); //2017
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1); //this starts at 0, not 1. Therefore, add 1


        if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 4) { //Is it the fourth of the month?
            System.out.println("fourth");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT THE FOURTH");
        }

        if ((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 4) && (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 == 8)) { //Is it the fourth of the month?
            System.out.println("fourth of august");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT THE FOURTH OF AUGUST");
        }

    }

}
```

Oh, and this will print the following

```
4
6
2017
8
fourth
fourth of august
```

**UPDATED FOR ANDROID STUDIO CODE**

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE)); //prints 4
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1); //this starts at 0, not 1. Therefore, add 1
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)); //2017

        if ((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 0 == 4) && (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 == 8)) { //Is it the fourth of the month of 2017?
            System.out.println("TODAY IS AN A DAY");
            textView.setText("Today is August Fourth");
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            textView.setText("Today is NOT August Fourth");
        }

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.vzw.www.calendar.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 2 things... it says I cannot use the number in the line if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) ==4 and where do I put this code so that it can display as a line of text on my app

Comment: show me your code. copy and paste in your opening comment.

Comment: It still only displays "Hello World!" on the Main Activity, not "TODAY IS AUGUST FOURTH" like it should

Comment: my code works.... there is something still wrong with your code. my code displays Today is August Fourth. If your code wasnt working, then itll display Today is NOT August Fourth. since that is the other condition. So yeah, your code is wrong....somewhere. my guess is its your ID for your textview.

Answer (score 0):

public class CheckDay {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE)); //prints 4
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1); //this starts at 0, not 1. Therefore, add 1
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)); //2017

    if ((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 0 == 4) && (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 == 8)) { //Is it the fourth of the month of 2017?
        System.out.println("TODAY IS AN A DAY");
    } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: @DroiDev is this what you are referring to?

Comment: What I'm confused about is, I have all this information which is great, but if I can't display it, it's not doing anything for me. I want to put this in my layouts  under home.xml, but all I have there currently is text views that say HOME and WELCOME. I want it to say "TODAY IS AN A DAY" below, which I got from the code above, but it's in a class, so I can't just insert a class.

Comment: do you not have experience in android?